# How to execute long bash sequence with Python subprocess

Tags: python, bash, subprocess

I wanna do this:

Bash code:

```
grub --batch << EOF
root (hd0,1)
find /boot/grub/menu.lst
setup (hd0)
quit
EOF
```

Python code:

```
subprocess.call('grub --batch << EOF', shell=True)
subprocess.call('root (hd0,1)', shell=True)
subprocess.call('find /boot/grub/menu.lst', shell=True)
subprocess.call('setup (hd0)', shell=True)
subprocess.call('quit', shell=True)
subprocess.call('EOF', shell=True)
```

But this doesn't work..
Somebody now the alternative way to solve this problem?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do just one call to `subprocess.call` with the entire command with newlines.

Comment: Yes, I thought this too. But didn't work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something horrible like:

`subprocess.call('echo -e "root (hd0,1)\nfind /boot/grub/menu.lst\nsetup (hd0)\nquit" | grub --batch', shell=True)`

I'm sure there is a better way to do this though.

Comment: Perfect..
Thanks.. I will try to put this code inside the project here.
But i think that will work.

Thanks for while!

Answer (score 6):

The solution is to send the script as one string:

```
script = '''
root (hd0,1)
find /boot/grub/menu.lst
setup (hd0)
quit
'''
print subprocess.Popen('grub', stderr=subprocess.STDOUT).communicate(script)[0]
```

`shell=True` should not be necessary.

Comment: +1: Embedding shell in Python (or any other language) is a good way to introduce maintenance headaches. You are constrained by needing grub to do the heavy lifting but use the intrinsic Python facilities as much as possible as Aaron has done.